# Fail to have HttpServletRequest with additional argument in a method in a controller

Tags: java, jersey

I cannot make my controller working when I add additional parameter when I have `HttpServletRequest` as one of its parameters. The following code compiles and gives no exceptions.

```
@POST
@Path("new")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String create(HttpServletRequest request) {

}
```

However, when I add additional parameter, an exception is thrown.

```
@POST
@Path("new")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String create(HttpServletRequest request,  ClientDto clientDto) {

}
```

Here's the exception:

```
[[FATAL] Method public java.lang.String CreditController.create(
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,dto.ClientDto) on resource class CreditController
contains multiple parameters with no annotation.
Unable to resolve the injection source.;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per suggestion of @GyroGearless:

It seems to missing `@Context` annotation, you can try with this like,

```
@POST
@Path("new")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String create(@Context HttpServletRequest request, ClientDto clientDto) {
```

Comment: And IIRR `@Context` for the `HttpServletRequest`

Comment: I added `public String create(HttpServletRequest request, @QueryParam("clientDto") ClientDto clientDto)` but the code now won't compile.

Comment: @GyroGearless Thanks! What was only needed is `@Context` annotation.